# AND / INDIRECT Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

What I am trying to achieve is if a cell in column AB equals "Yes" and a cell in column AC is blank, then a certain range of cells will be formatted. Currently the rule is not formatting cells that it should. I am basing this code on another formatting rule I am using that works properly, but does not use AND().

```
=AND(INDIRECT("ab"&ROW())="Yes", INDIRECT("ac"&ROW())="")
```

I am sure this is an obvious syntax mistake, but I am still very new to Excel and can't figure out why this isn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

`=AND($AB1="YES",$AC1="")`

Use the format painter to drag the formula around.

As `Jeeped` said, change the `1` in `$AB1` and `$AC1` to your first row.

[image: Demo]

Comment: The **1** in `$AB1` and `$AC1` should be the same as the first row in your CFR's Applies To: range.